# How can I flatten/expand lists embedded in a data frame?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data frame in which one column is a list of vectors, with various lengths. This code creates an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  A=c("able", "baker", "carr"),
  B=c("whiskey", "tango", "foxtrot")
)
df1$C <- list(14, c(2,18,32), c(10,6))
```

The actual data originated in an SPSS database. (BTW, I could not figure out how to create this example with a single statement.)

I'd like to convert it to a data frame like the one created by the following code:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  A=c("able", rep("baker",3), rep("carr",2)),
  B=c("whiskey", rep("tango",3), rep("foxtrot",2)),
  C=c(14, 2, 18, 32, 10, 6)
)
```

I don't want to resort to ugly surgery and looping -- been there, done that.

Comment: `library(tidyr)` then `unnest(df1, cols = "C")` should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Not explicit looping, and not sure whether or not this is ugly surgery, but here is a base R approach, much cleaner thanks to @onyambu

```
# For each row Unroll by length of df1$C: res => data.frame
res <- transform(
  df1[
    rep(
      seq(
        nrow(df1)
      ),
      lengths(df1$C)
    ),
  ], 
  C = unlist(df1$C), 
  row.names = NULL
)
```

Comment: if yu gonna use `base R` do something like `transform(df1[rep(seq(ncol(df1)),lengths(df1$C)),], C = unlist(df1$C), row.names = NULL)`

Comment: @onyambu yep thats much cleaner but i think you mean: `transform(
  df1[rep(seq(nrow(df1)),lengths(df1$C)),], 
  C = unlist(df1$C), 
  row.names = NULL
)`

Comment: curious, What is the difference between that and the one I posted?

Comment: you used `ncol()` inside your `seq()` function which only words here because ncol(df) == nrow(df)

Comment: yesyes, you are right!! Missed thhat. Why do you have every function on its own row?

Comment: @onyambu all good, what you meant in your solution was much cleaner than what I had originally conceived

Comment: @onyambu i do a lot of database work and I guess its just habitual now, not really sure, i find it cleaner and easier to understand going down as opposed to left to right. Not sure if this is best practice.

Comment: You could use the native pipes though. Anyway SQL is often need line by line for sure

Comment: @onyambu i don't get to really use much R anymore in my day-to-day work so I use SO as a way of trying to keep my R relatively sharp, reading alot of your solutions has certainly helped in this regard so thanks for that too !

Comment: @onyambu true but Pipes only came about relatively recently and a lot of people use older versions of R in corporations / governments where I am from (Australia), so I try and keep my solutions backwards compatible if that makes sense. Also alot of people dont have access to download and install packages without IT approvals which may never happen, so I try to avoid `::magrittr` pipes and tidyverse for that reason.

Comment: I was actually refering to base R pipes. If you have >4.0 you should be able to use the native pipes. Though you are right, for backward compatibility we beter stick to the normal flow

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyr)
df2 <- unnest(df1, cols = "C")
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  A     B           C
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
1 able  whiskey    14
2 baker tango       2
3 baker tango      18
4 baker tango      32
5 carr  foxtrot    10
6 carr  foxtrot     6
```